# Empty Script Task when running from Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, sql-agent

I'm having trouble running a DTS in SQL Server Agent. The job runs perfectly in VS2015 but the Script Task is not loading (is empty) when I upload it to the SQL Server Agent Job.

There is no error, just that the script task is empty (my code is not loading).

Comment: This is a tough one. There isn't much in the way of details here but given the scenario it would be difficult to post much. Unless somebody else has experienced this and figured out a solution I don't know that this is likely going to find an answer. :(

Comment: @SeanLange it's a simple ETL process. The Script Task is used to send a HTML formatted email. When I upload the DTS to the server all seems to work perfectly, but the Script Task is empty.

Comment: Right I got that from your description. I have never seen or heard of this happening before so replicating the issue is nearly impossible. I am hopeful for you that somebody else has experienced this.

Comment: If you're running this through a SQL Server Agent Job, then you're probably having to apply a Proxy with a credential, which is then applying a network logon account.  Have you checked the permissions of that logon account?  If it does not have the same access as the one you're applying in VS20015, then that could account for the result you mentioned.  Test this by logging into VS2015 with that network account applied in the Proxy defined in your SQL Server Agent Job.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the `Target Version` property.

Right click on the project >> Properties >> Configuration properties >> General >> Change `Target version` to **SQL Server 2012**

**Additional information**

- [Backwards Compatibility in SQL Server Data Tools for Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/)